# keybd_event doesn't work in activex,postmessage does,but can't simulate VK_BACK

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, activex

I'm developing a browser plugin which would interact with javascript. I used the open-source framework **firebreath** to develop the plugin which would pack **NPAPI**(non-ie browsers) plugin and **activex**(used in ie) in one **dll** file.

The following code works perfectly under non-ie browsers which uses the **NPAPI** plugin("**enter**","**delete**","**backspace**" keys can be pressed correctly):

```
//VKey stands for the key users pressed like "VK_RETURN","VK_BACK","VK_DELETE",etc
 keybd_event(Vkey,0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | 0,0);
```

But if I run the plugin in **ie**,nothing happens.I tried **SendInput** too,but still **nothing** happens:

```
    KEYBDINPUT kb={0}; 
    INPUT Input={0};  
    kb.wScan = VK_BACK; 
    kb.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;  
    Input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD; 
    Input.ki = kb;      
    ::SendInput(1,&Input,sizeof(Input));
```

Which is odd is the combination of keys works correctly in ie. eg(ctrl+x):

```
>   keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, MapVirtualKey(VK_CONTROL,0), 0 ,0);
>   keybd_event(bCharKey,(BYTE)0, 0 ,0);    
>   Sleep(10);
>   keybd_event(bCharKey,(BYTE)0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
>   keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, MapVirtualKey(VK_CONTROL,0),
>   KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
```

So I change the keybd_event to PostMessage:

```
    ::PostMessage(hbrowser,WM_KEYDOWN,vKey,1); //vKey stands for key pressed    
    ::PostMessage(hbrowser,WM_KEYUP,vKey,1);
```

"**VK_TAB**","**VK_DELETE**","**VK_RETURN**","**VK_TAB**","**VK_SPACE**" works,but "**VK_BACK**" doesn't work.

Comment: Can sombody help me please. It has bothered me for 2 days